# Accessing JS Class/Object Variables Via Instance Methods and This - Execution Contexts

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, arrow-functions, executioncontext

First Question: Why is the value for `this` in getXArrow() equal to the Solution object? Shouldn't it equal the `this` value of the solution object which called it, which would be the Window object?

Second Question: Shouldn't the JS Engine travel up the scope chain of each function to find the value of x? The scope of getX() and getXArrow() don't have `x`, so the JS engine would check their caller (the Solution object) and find `x: 10`, as declared in the constructor. Instead, it seems to jump up to the global scope?

```
let x = 5
class Solution {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 10
    }
    getX() {
        console.log(this); 
        console.log(x); 
    }
    getXArrow = () => {
        console.log(this); 
        console.log(x); 
    }
}

s.getXArrow() // Output: Solution
              //         5
s.getX()      // Output: Solution
              //         5
```

Thank you!

Comment: A class method's `this` is the instance object itself, by default. class members are not hoisted into the lexical scope like they are in other langs; you have to use `this.x` to reach _that_ `x`

Comment: JS has lexical scope, it doesn't matter who the caller is. There is only one `x` variable in your script anyway - a property is not a variable.

Comment: Please ask a single question per post only. Btw, your first question can be easily researched by looking for how arrow functions work.

Answer (score 1):

`getX` just has two scopes accessible: It's own function scope and the global scope. Classes don't create a scope, and thus `x` cannot be accessed. You do however have access to the instance via `this` and can access its `.x` property.